# why passing in a temp variable into const ref in ctor work?

Tags: c++

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct foo
{
    int d_member;

    foo(const int & in):
    d_member(in){};
};

int main()
{
    foo *p;

    {
        int temp = 5;
        p = new foo(temp);
    }

    std::cout << p->d_member << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Foo takes a const ref in it's ctor to a int, and I passed a temporary int to it.
temp is destroyed after new. Why I am still able to print out d_member?

Comment: It would work without the `const` too.

Comment: Because you're not maintaining a reference beyond the constructor call.

Comment: If you change `d_member` to `const int &d_member;`, *then* you'll have a problem since `d_member` will also get bound to `temp` and then `temp` will go away. Because of how the stack works in most compilers, the behavior probably won't change, but the standard doesn't mandate what will happen when you try to evaluate `p->d_member`. At that point the program technically has *undefined behavior* and could do anything at all, including: (1) crash, (2) do what you want, (3) or something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your constructor initialization list **copies** the integer argument to the member variable.  The lifetime of your member variable is the lifetime of your object.

Answer (score 6):

As others already mentioned with a non reference member variable your constructor call simply copies the value from the `const` reference parameter (and it even doesn't matter if you pass it by reference or value).

You would have a different situation, if your member variable is a reference like

```
struct foo
{
    const int& d_member; // <<<< reference member variable

    foo(const int & in): d_member(in){};
};
```

In that case, accessing `d_member` after your scope block would raise *undefined behavior*:

```
{
    int temp = 5;
    p = new foo(temp);
}

std::cout << p->d_member << std::endl; // <<<<  Undefined behavior
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `temp` is destroyed, but before that it was copied during `d_member(in)` initialization. So nothing is wrong here